# PhpThumb error - PHP Fatal error: Class 'PhpThumb' not found

Tags: php, phpthumb

I had downloaded from official website, uploaded to my hosting server. I got this error message.

```
[08-Mar-2012 21:26:07] PHP Fatal error: Class 'PhpThumb' not found in /home/sokad
/public_html/libs/phpthumb/thumb_plugins/gd_reflection.inc.php on line 179 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Cannot show image, headers 
have already been sent' in /home/sokad/public_html/libs/phpthumb/GdThumb.inc.php:569 Stack 
trace: #0 /home/sokad/public_html/resize.php(14): GdThumb->show() #1 {main} thrown in 
/home/sokad/public_html/libs/phpthumb/GdThumb.inc.php on line 569

require_once 'libs/phpthumb/ThumbLib.inc.php';

$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($url);
$thumb->adaptiveResize($width, $height);
$thumb->show();
```

I found that a lot of website also got same problem. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: what have you tried? the error its a pretty common one, im almos sure that you are lacking a require somewhere

Comment: What is not clear from the error message? `Class 'PhpThumb' not found in /home/sokad
/public_html/libs/phpthumb/thumb_plugins/gd_reflection.inc.php on line 179 `

Answer (score -1):

scan your "phpthumb" directory for all "error_log" files or "_notes" directories, and delete them. In my case I had an error_log file at the thumb_plugins, as soon as I deleted it, it worked on the remote side.

I came to this conclusion because there was no reason why it whould work differently locally and remotely, the only difference? these files.

Good Luck